# Why Query_parallelism affects the result of a join between two UUID columns

Tags: ignite

I'm running the following test on ignite 2.10.0

I have 2 tables created with a query_parallelism=1 and without affinity key.
When I join the 2 following tables I have the result as expected.

```
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost:10800> SELECT "id" AS "_A_id", "source_id" AS "_A_source_id" FROM PUBLIC."source_ml_blue";
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                _A_id                 |             _A_source_id             |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 86c068cd-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 | 86c068cc-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.004 seconds)
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost:10800> SELECT "id" AS "_B_id", "flx_src_ip_text" AS "_B_src_ip" FROM PUBLIC."source_nprobe_tcp_blue";
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|                _B_id                 | _B_src_ip |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| 86c068cc-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 | 1.1.1.1   |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+
1 row selected (0.003 seconds)
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost:10800> SELECT _A."id" AS "_A_id", _A."source_id" AS "_A_source_id", _B."id"  AS "_B_id", _B."flx_src_ip_text" AS "_B_src_ip" FROM PUBLIC."source_ml_blue" AS "_A" INNER JOIN  PUBLIC."source_nprobe_tcp_blue" AS "_B" ON "_A"."source_id"="_B"."id";
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|                _A_id                 |             _A_source_id             |                _B_id                 | _B_src_ip |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| 86c068cd-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 | 86c068cc-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 | 86c068cc-da89-11eb-a185-3da86c6c6bb3 | 1.1.1.1   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
1 row selected (0.005 seconds)
```

If I delete and create the same tables with a query_parallelism = 8, I do not have a SQL error (the parallelism is equal on the 2 tables) BUT the result of the join is empty.

any idea why I get this behavior ?

Comment: I am not getting the same results w/
CREATE TABLE table1 (   id int PRIMARY KEY,  x int, ) WITH  "template=cacheTemplate"
Then same for table2 and join:  SELECT * FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID  
Here  CacheTemplate is defined w/QueryParallelism of 8. Post all your table/cache definitions and I'll take a look.

Comment: using int is not a problem, please try to use uuid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the SQL client : it has to be aware of the parallelism.

On DBeaver, I had to enable ignite.jdbc.distributedJoins in the connection properties to make the request works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You observe this behaviour because of optimisations for parallel query execution. Most likely your records landed to different partitions (handled by a different thread). If you increase the number of records in both tables you will see a subset of this join as a result.
The most elegant option here is to let `"_A"."source_id"` and `"_B"."id"` be [affinity keys](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/affinity-collocation#configuring-affinity-key). Most likely `ignite.jdbc.distributedJoins` is going to affect performance for clustered installation. Affinity collocation will make items with matching `"_A"."source_id"` and `"_B"."id"` reside in the same partition to avoid cross-partitional interaction (for clustered environments it would lead to additional networks hops).

Comment: The test was performed on a cluster with a single node. Without the distributedJoins option, DBeaver is not able to retrieve all the data.

Comment: Do you mean that affinity doesn't help? Without affinity it's logical that it doesn't work as keys are distributed and processed on the per-partition basis.

Comment: The test was performed without the affinity key on purpose, I will add this info in the question.